# Unordered Map equality functionality c++

Tags: c++, unordered-map

May be this is easy but I just want to understand if we can do this:

Let say we have an `unordered_map(string, string)` so by default it will check for equality if two strings are equal.

Now, let say if we add one more functionality in equality operator that even if two strings are anagrams of each other then also return true. In order to this, can we only update the equality operator and not the hasher(and use the default hasher).

For instance, only defining functor for:

```
bool operator() (const string& a, const string& b) const  
{  
    // check for anagram condition here  
}
```

Comment: Sort each string, then hash, compare, etc.

Comment: @Jerry: Sorry, but din't get you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Equal objects have to have the same hash, otherwise a hash table will look for values in the wrong bucket. For example, the strings ab and ba probably end up in different buckets, so when you look up ab you cannot find ba even though they should be "equal."

So no, you can't use the default hash function.

Comment: You should use some hash function invariant with permutations, like e.g. the sum of individual `char`-s of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the default hash function and your custom equal operator. Use the hash std::hash and equal to as you custom operator.

```
template<
   class Key,
   class T,
   class Hash = std::hash<Key>,
   class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>,
   class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>
>     class unordered_map;
```

Comment: But this will probably not have the effect OP is after. Two anagrams will not be treated as having equal keys.